# Dropdownlistfor throwing exception System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>.Model.get returned null

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get value from dropdownlistfor ,I can see values in dropdownlist  when i run my code but when i submit ,it is throwing error
" **System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.Model.get returned null.** "

It not happening always.when I run First time after reopen application it work fine but after that it gives me this error even I don't change anything from the code.

```html
@model ProjectDentalweb.Models.Viewmodel.Makeappointment

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Schedule";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.demo</h2>
<h2>@ViewBag.demo2</h2>
<h2>appointment</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Schedule", "Patient"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<h2>@ViewBag.demo</h2>
<h2>@ViewBag.demo2</h2>
<div class="form-horizontal">
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.appointments.PatientName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBox("PatientName", (string)ViewBag.Uname, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.appointments.PatientName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.appointments.AppointmentDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.appointments.AppointmentDate, "{0: d mm yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control datepick" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.appointments.AppointmentDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.appointments.Did, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.appointments.Did, new SelectList(Model.doctors, "DoctorId", "DoctorName"), "Select Doctor", new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.appointments.Did, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.appointments.Reason, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.appointments.Reason, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.appointments.Reason, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.appointments.AppointmentStatus, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.appointments.AppointmentStatus, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.appointments.AppointmentStatus, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>



</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn-primary">Create</button>
}
```

Controller //

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Schedule()

    {
        if (Session["Username"] != null)
        {
            var x = Session["Username"];
            var U = _context.Patients.Single(m => m.UserLogin.UserName == (string)x).FirstName;
            ViewBag.Uname = U;

            //ViewBag.Dlist = _context.Doctors.ToList();

            var Viewmodel = new Makeappointment // Get doctor info in dropdownlist for appointment table
            {
                doctors = _context.Doctors.ToList()
            };
            return View("Schedule",Viewmodel);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Signin", "Useraccess");
        }

    }

    // POST : Patient / Schedule 
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Schedule(Makeappointment makeappointment)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var demo = Session["Username"];
            var U = _context.Patients.Single(m => m.UserLogin.UserName == (string)demo);
            int Uid = Convert.ToInt32(U.PatientId);
            Appointment appointment = new Appointment();
            appointment.Pid = Uid;

            appointment.PatientName = makeappointment.appointments.PatientName;
            appointment.AppointmentDate = makeappointment.appointments.AppointmentDate;
            appointment.Did = makeappointment.appointments.Did.Value;
            appointment.Reason = makeappointment.appointments.Reason;
            appointment.AppointmentStatus = false;
            _context.Appointments.Add(appointment);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Appointment", "Patient");
        }
        else
        {

        }
        return View();
    }

}
```

<-------------------------------------------->

Viewmodel //

namespace ProjectDentalweb.Models.Viewmodel
{

```
public class Makeappointment
{


    public Appointment appointments { get; set; }
    public IList<Doctor> doctors { get; set; }


}
```

}

[image: Error]

Comment: You have not shown your controller code, but almost certainly because you return the view in the POST method and have not repopulated `Model.doctors` as you did in the GET method, therefore its `null`

Comment: Can you please tell me how do i repopulate model.doctors in post method?

Comment: Just as you did in the GET method - `makeappointment.doctors = _context.Doctors.ToList(); return View(makeappointment);`

Comment: Still not working , I used breakpoints on post method. But it snot even going inside post method. When i click submit i get's an error

Comment: Its a server side error, so it must be hitting your POST method (and the error message you posted confirms it - you have not returned the model as I noted above so its `null` and `new SelectList(Model.doctors, ...)` throws the exception

Comment: If `ModelState.IsValid` returns false, then your code will use `return View()` without any model passed and so throwing exception when instantiating `SelectList`. Put `makeappointment.doctors = _context.Doctors.ToList()` inside `else` block and then use `return View(makeappointment)` instead of `return View()`.

Answer (score 0):

This error may be caused by trying to use a null model in razor view. In such situation check if the model is null or not before using as shown below:

```
@if (Model != null) { 
    <a onclick="get('@Url.Action("DemoAction", "DemoController")', @Model.Id)" ></a>
}
```